# Validating for Binary codes and repeating program without infinite loop

Tags: java

I was assigned to make a program that converts Binary to decimal. I got that part done with no problems but I have to validate what the user inputs to make sure they put in binary or else it should say "try again" I also have to keep the program repeating using letter "y/Y" to continue or else it exists without using an infinite loop. I have no idea how to do it without an infinite loop. Thank you

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
class Quiz4 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
       System.out.print("Enter a binary number: ");
       String binaryString =input.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Output: "+Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code here, not an offsite image.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that you've posted some code, you need to read (and understand) your requirements.

Judging on your post, the concrete requirement is to not use an "infinite loop" - I would interpret that to mean I'm allowed to use a conditional loop.

So, assuming I understand your requirements, I would:

1. Wrap existing code in a do/while loop, since you want to evaluate at the end of execution.
2. Write some code to read from the keyboard.
3. Exit the above loop when keyboard input is appropriate (e.g. `(!myvar.toLower().equals("y"))` ).

Feel free to write the code & update your post, and if needed, I'll update this answer. Apologies, but writing the code for you is, in my opinion, both against the spirit of SO and counter-productive for your studies.

However, another way to solve the problem, is recursion. If your teacher is really asking you to solve *this* problem by recursion, I would seriously consider finding another teacher.

Answer (score 0):

This following function may be used to ensure input has only 1's and 0's.

```
private static boolean hasOnly1sAnd0s(String s) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) 
        // have character that is not 1 or 0
        if( !( s.charAt(i)== '1' || s.charAt(i)== '0' ) )
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

So, say you have something like this to accept user input,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a binary number: ");

    // in contains a potential binary string
    String in = scanner.nextLine();

    // first check to see if it is a binary string
    boolean isBinaryString = hasOnly1sAnd0s( in );

    // loop till user wants to keep trying again and enters invalid binary string
    while (!isBinaryString) {
        System.out.print("Try again? ");

        // if 'y' or 'Y', let user input number, else break out of loop
        char c = scanner.next(".").charAt(0);
        if (!(c == 'y' || c == 'Y'))
            break;

        // take input
        System.out.println("Enter a binary number: "); 
        in = scanner.next();

        // check if input is valid binary string
        isBinaryString = hasOnly1sAnd0s( in );
    }

    // the string `in` contains a valid binary string iff isBinaryString == true
    // otherwise, it is the case that user inputted `no` for "Try again"
    if (isBinaryString)
        System.out.println("Output: " + Integer.parseInt( in , 2));
}
```

EDIT: (explain file structure to OP)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ......
    }

    private static boolean hasOnly1sAnd0s(String s) {
        ......
    }
}
```

I know this seems a little code-heavy. But, did I manage to help you out?

Comment: im not sure how to implement that onto my code without getting massive errors

Comment: @MontyOsman It would just go inside your `main`. Anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: I put it right after the 'System.out.println("Output: "+Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2));' but it continues to give massive errors

Comment: @MontyOsman Made a minor edit and tested - seems fine. For future reference, `massive error` means **nothing**. It would be much easier if you could use a debugger and be particular about the error.

Comment: @MontyOsman It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Comment: @MontyOsman. No no no. You replace your `main(...)` with the one I have written. And you can place the `hasOnly1sAnd0s(..)` before or after.

Comment: @MontyOsman see how your class should look in the edit. Or [click here](http://ideone.com/hrABcQ).